# How do I best package a global configuration scheme?

Tags: packaging

I've been working on creating a Linux configuration scheme based on my own system configuration. It consists of

1. A configuration of the Interception program [Dual Function Keys](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/plugins/dual-function-keys).
2. A custom keyboard layout with several higher layers.
3. A configuration of [StumpWM](https://github.com/stumpwm).
4. A configuration of Emacs. This configuration is supposed to come in two variants:

- a basic one which is maybe most analogous to evil mode, a configuration scheme which remaps the commands in Emacs itself.
- Another one, which assumes the existence of several plugins to both rebind keys and to add and replace commands which would thus be a bit more like Spacemacs or Doom Emacs in scope.

5. A configuration of the Firefox Plugin Tridactyl.

All of these are attuned to each other. Furthermore, I made in the course of creating the Emacs configuration two parts which I think I should make into packages on their own. But apart from those I'm not sure how to best integrate the entire thing into the software it uses. I also don't assume that a user would just adopt it at once, the parts build on each other but not all of them depend on all others. For instance, it would be possible to only use the Dual Function Keys config, the keyboard layout and the Emacs configuration while not using StumpWM or Tridactyl. I'm also thinking of introducing a variant of the keyboard layout whose lower two layers are fairly normal QWERTY. So for instance I'm not sure whether I should try to get the Emacs parts into MELPA or not, and whether to put them in together or not, since the advanced version uses commands from the basic one. Should I try to get each part into the service that usually distributes its kind or should I just put them all up together for now? How should I best proceed to make the installation as easy as possible while still retaining modularity as much as possible?